# .htaccess help - need to rediect from incoming subdomain to new page

Tags: .htaccess

I am going to be changing the CNAME record of one of my sub-domains, but I need all traffic from this including  files, pages, etc. to be redirected to a new page on the new domain.

Example:
 redirect all traffic from xxx.example.com to www.example.com/xxx/xxx

Comment: Just telling us what you need is not sufficient. Please show some effort. What did you try? Also, it's not clear what exactly you want

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.xxx\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxx.com/xxx/xxx/$1 [R=301,L]
```